# Create an PHP Array for highcharts

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an multiple array set for an highchart as you can see here [HighChart Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/)

PHP code to retrieve data from the database.

```
    $sql = <<< SQL
             SELECT TOP (
             [miles]
            ,[status]
            FROM [database].[dbo].[portal]
  SQL;

$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$rowCount = $result->fetchColumn();

$dataset = array('name' => 'Naam');

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $data[] = $row['automillage'];
}


array_push($dataset, $data);
echo json_encode($dataset,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

The current output of my array is

```
       {
        0: [
            1000,
            2297,
            1500,
            3301,
           ],
        name: "Naam"
       }
```

But what i really want is starting with data instead of starting with 0:

```
           {
        Data: [
            1000,
            2297,
            1500,
            3301,
           ],
        name: "Naam"
       }
```

And I am wondering how i can get two data series in one array.

Tnx to @bassxzero i have now the right output.

But I want to achieve one more thing. Getting two data series in one array like in the Example:

```
    series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
}]
```

When I try to json_decode the two arrays, I get an error while compiling the code.

**- The error code is: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

```
$dataset['Data'] = $data;
$dataset2['Data'] = $data2;
$join[] = json_decode($dataset, true);
$join[] = json_decode($dataset2, true);


echo json_encode($join,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

And after that i want to update it with json. My code is like this:

```
            var chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: ''
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: ''
            }]
        });

        function chartUpdate() {
            $.getJSON("dbcon/connection - Copy.php", function (dataset) {
                chart.update({
                    series: [{
                        data: dataset
                    }]
                });
            });
        } //end chartUpdate
```

Comment: change `array_push($dataset, $data);` to `$dataset['Data']= $data;`

Comment: Damn it :) Thank you very much for your answer. 

Do you also know how I can make this array repeat with other values so i can get the series name: 'name', data: [ data ], name: 'name 2', data: [ data2] with the array?

see my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:- `array_push()` creating a numeric index,while you need an associative index.

So, Instead of:-

```
array_push($dataset, $data);
```

do:-

```
$dataset['Data'] = $data;
```

***pass two arrays in one array output:***

```
$dataset['data'] = $data;
$dataset2['data'] = $data2;
$join[] = json_decode(json_encode($dataset), true);
$join[] = json_decode(json_encode($dataset2), true);

echo json_encode($join,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Sergio did you checked the answer?

Comment: Sorry I saw it too late. Already passed the answer in this post. Thank you for your time and support.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the data with a key instead of just pushing it to the array.

```
$dataset['Data'] = $data
```

EDIT: @bassxzero beat me to it in his comment.

Comment: Thank you Jim for your answer. Do you know ho I can get the second series into the same array without making a new array? See my updated question. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergio  check my answer for that

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank you for the answers.

**The answer for getting the array in the right output was thanx to bassxzero:**

```
Change: array_push($dataset, $data); to $dataset['Data']= $data;
```

**The answer to pass two arrays in one array output:**

```
$dataset['data'] = $data;
$dataset2['data'] = $data2;
$join[] = json_decode(json_encode($dataset), true);
$join[] = json_decode(json_encode($dataset2), true);

echo json_encode($join,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: I tried already, but if I don't use two variables I don't get the result I am looking for.

I want to achieve this: https://ibb.co/bxuWN6
With two variables I am able to make it work.