# How to remove starting / ending square brackets from array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, square-bracket

In my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870219/create-an-php-array-for-highcharts) question I was able to generate the array I was looking for. At this moment I am struggling with the starting blockquote. The block quote at the beginning and at the end has to be removed.

**My code:**

```
$options['chart']    = array('type' => 'line');
$options['title']    = array('text' => 'Monthly report');
$options['subtitle'] = array('text' => 'Milage');
$options['xAxis']    = array('categories' => "Jan, Feb, 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'");

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data1[] = $row['automillage'];
    $data2[] = $row['dealer_status'];
}

$naam1 = array('name' => 'Data series 1');
$naam2 = array('name' => 'Data series 2');

$dataset1['data'] = $data1;
$dataset2['data'] = $data2;

$series1[] = $naam1+$dataset1;
$series2[] = $naam2+$dataset2;

$mergeData1['series'] =  array_merge($series1,$series2);

$join[] = json_decode(json_encode($options), true);
$join[] = json_decode(json_encode($mergeData1), true);

echo json_encode($join,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

My output https://ibb.co/n2vM76

What can I do to delete the first and last blockquote

Comment: Now it's array of 2 objects? how do you see to combine them ?

Comment: And those aren't blockquotes, they are square brackets/braces.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Your edit didn't make you desired output possible.

Comment: `$mergeData1['series'] =  array_merge($series1, $series2, $options);
echo json_encode($mergeData1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, those aren't blockquotes. They're square brackets, and they indicate an array, which `$join` is (I assume you know that). You can't get rid of them, because it is an array. If you're looking to merge the two associative array you have into one array, instead of creating an array of two arrays, the best raw method (in my opinion) would be to loop through one object, and assign it's properties by key to the other. Of course, since you're setting all the values anyway, you could just set them all into one array from the start. Bare in mind that as you're creating an associative array, which doesn't exist in JSON, it translates that into an object.

As long as your arrays have different keys, you can also use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or add the two arrays together (`$array1 + $array2`).

Comment: Hi, yes I know it is an array. I am new to this programming language and starting to do some advanced code step by step. I am not sure how to loop exactly to get the result I want, but I will give it a try as you mentioned.

Comment: I realized you have different keys in both arrays, so updated my answer; rather than looping, you can use `array_merge` or array addition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. See my code below. I am not sure it this is the best practice but I have the output I want. 

[See](https://ibb.co/fkZ9um)

Comment: You typically don't want to put your fixed code as an answer; rather mark an answer you used as correct so if someone else sees the question, they have some direction to work from. That said, your code is far more verbose than necessary, and doesn't really scale well (why have `$dataset1` and `$dataset2`? why not just an array with two dataset values with 1 and 2 as keys?), it does what you want now.

Comment: If I don't do that, it won't seperate the second name and data values with the curly bracket ( { ) or am I wrong with that? 

it will start data: [2,3,4,], name: "test" ....  instead of data: [1,2,3,4] }, name: "test"

If you look carefully to the code how it must be delivered you can see what i mean (or I don't understand what you mean :) )... 

in the series part i have name and data, the first set is between curly brackets and the second set is also between curly brackets. if I don't use two variables i don't get the result

Comment: This will end up an extended discussion, but it doesn't sound like you're learning PHP, rather it looks like you're just expecting an output and trying to force code to fit that. There is no difference between having an array with two values and referencing either key, and having two variables and referencing either one, besides organization. Plus, if you end up needing a third set, you can add a new key, rather than create a new variable. You understand WHY the JSON has curly braces, right?

Comment: I am learning, but anyway if something is new for me and if I am trying to figure out how it works, that does not mean that I am forcing to fit the output. Will check your suggestion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161691/discussion-between-sergio-and-rhovisions).